# R seems to ignore part of variable name after underscore

Tags: r, variables, variable-names

I encountered a strange problem with R. I have a dataframe with several variables. I add a variable to this dataframe that contains an underscore, for example:

```
allres$tmp_weighted <- allres$day * allres$area
```

Before I do this, R tells me that the variable `allres$tmp` does not exist (which is right). However, after I add `allres$tmp_weighted` to the dataframe and call `allres$tmp`, I get the data for `allres$tmp_weighted`. It seems as if the part after the underscore does not matter at all for R. I tried it with several other variables / names and it always works that way

I don't think this should work like this? Am I overlooking something here? Below I pasted some code together with output from the Console.

```
# first check whether variable exists
allres_sw$Ndpsw

> NULL

#define new variable with underscore in variable name
allres_sw$Ndpsw_weighted <- allres_sw$Ndepswcrit * allres_sw$Area

#check again whether variable exists
allres_sw$Ndpsw

>   [1]    17.96480   217.50240    44.84415    42.14560     0.00000    43.14444    53.98650     9.81939     0.00000   110.67720

# this is the output that I would expect from "Ndpsw_weighted" - and indeed do get
allres_sw$Ndpsw_weighted
>   [1]    17.96480   217.50240    44.84415    42.14560     0.00000    43.14444    53.98650     9.81939     0.00000   110.67720
```

Comment: I have the same problem as your first problem - R is not reading the entire variable name it is stopping at an underscore and then complaining the variable doesn't exist (which is true). Did you resolve that?

Comment: Hi Simon, that sounds like a different problem - in my case it was never the issue that R did *not* recognise a variable, only that it *did* recognise a variable based on part of its name (which was behaviour that I didn't expect, but is to be expected when using the $ operator as explained by Will below.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `` ?`[` `` or `` ?`$` `` in your R console.  If you look at the `name` argument of the [extract](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) functions it states that names are partially matched when using the `$` operator (as opposed to the `` `[[` `` operator, which uses exact matches based on the `exact = TRUE` argument).

From `` ?`$` ``

> A literal character string or a name (possibly backtick quoted). For extraction, this is normally (see under ‘Environments’) partially matched to the names of the object.

Comment: Thanks Wil! This is really new to me. So it has (as Armali also points out) nothing to do with the underscore.

Comment: @Lena that is correct, it doesn't have anything to do with the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand somewhat on Wil's answer... From `help('$')`:

> ```
> x$name
> ```
>
> `name`
>   
>   A literal character string or a [name](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/name.html) (possibly [backtick](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html)
>   quoted).  For extraction, this is normally (see under
>   ‘Environments’) partially matched to the [`names`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/names.html)
>   of the object.
>
> `x$name` is equivalent to
>   `x[["name", exact = FALSE]]`.  Also, the partial matching
>   behavior of `[[` can be controlled using the `exact` argument.
>
> `exact`
>   
>   Controls possible partial matching of `[[` when
>   extracting by a character vector (for most objects, but see under
>   ‘Environments’).  The default is no partial matching.  Value
>   `NA` allows partial matching but issues a warning when it
>   occurs.  Value `FALSE` allows partial matching without any
>   warning.

The key phrase here is *partial match* (see [`pmatch`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pmatch.html)). You'll understand now that the underscore is nothing special - you can abbreviate `allres_sw$Ndpsw_weighted` to `allres_sw$Ndp`, provided no name is more similar than `allres_sw$Ndepswcrit`.

Comment: Thanks Armali for the elaborate answer. Indeed it has nothing to do with the underscore - I was looking in the wrong direction. I can see now that if I insert allres_sw[["Ndpsw", exact = TRUE]] I don't get the results for "Ndpsw_weighted" .  I can see that the partial match makes coding faster (cause you don't have to type the whole variable name), but I would also think it  makes coding more prone to errors (accidentally mis-typing a name might not lead to an error message because what you typed is the partial name of another variable).  But I guess that's just the way it is.